# returning #disabled in ajax callback

Tags: forms, ajax

This is taken from the examples module(http://drupal.org/project/examples). More specifically in the 'Generate textfields' ajax section. The form attempts to demonstrate an ajax call by presenting 2 checkboxes and generating a textfield based on which checkbox was clicked.

This is the ajax callback. We have a textfield with key 'first_name'.

```
function ajax_example_autotextfields_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $a = $form['first_name'];
  $a['first_name']['#value'] = 'foobar';
  $a['first_name']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
 return $a;
}
```

The form rendered has value textfield with value 'foobar' as expected, but the textfield is not disabled? How come?

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish that using [ajax_command_invoke](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_invoke/7).

Here is an example using your own code:

```
function ajax_example_autotextfields_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // $a = $form['first_name'];
  // $a['first_name']['#value'] = 'foobar';
  // $a['first_name']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  // return $a;

  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
      // First we add the disable attribute into the html input tag.
      // which makes the the input field inaccessible. 
      ajax_command_invoke('#WRAPPER_SELECTOR input', 'attr', array('disabled','disabled')),
      // Then we grey it out by adding the form-disabled CSS class.
      ajax_command_invoke('#WRAPPER_SELECTOR .form-item', 'addClass', array('form-disabled')),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can instead grey out using CSS attributes by calling [ajax_command_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_css/7)

Comment: Awesome one !! very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution (if you don't want to use ajax commands).

```
function ajax_example_autotextfields_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $a = $form['first_name'];
  $a['first_name']['#value'] = 'foobar';
  $a['first_name']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
 return $a;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be way simpler than my solution. Thanks for sharing.