# AJAX event and disable select form element

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a little problem:

```
/**
 * Form callback
 */
function ajax_disable_test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#title' => t('Change me!'),
    '#empty_option' => t('- Select -'),
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(range(1, 3)),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="select_box_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $form['change'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Change!'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_disable_test_form_submit_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'select_box_wrapper',
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Ajax callback
 */
function ajax_disable_test_form_submit_ajax($form, $form_state) {
  $form['select']['#title'] = t('Changed!'); // It's work!
  $form['select']['#disabled'] = TRUE; // It's not work!
  return $form['select'];
}
```

Link: https://gist.github.com/nevergone/23f0a50bee01acc34ed2

If clicked the button, select box title changed, but select box not disabled. Why?
Version: Drupal 7.41

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20321/returning-disabled-in-ajax-callback

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$form['select']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
```

Ok, a detailed explanation can be found on this article https://www.drupal.org/node/357328

But pretty much resumes to:

> we cannot simple set the $element['#disabled'] attribute of the
>   element. The reason is this attribute is transformed into
>   $element['#attributes']['disabled'] by
>   _form_builder_handle_input_element executes()...

Comment: Please try explaining why the code works. A code-only answer doesn't explain why it works or what the asker did wrong in the first place.

Comment: ok, some background was added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild your form. Have a look at the [Ajax Framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) docs for further information.

```
<?php

/**
 * Form callback
 *
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function ajax_disable_test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#title' => t('Change me!'),
    '#empty_option' => t('- Select -'),
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(range(1, 3)),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="select_box_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['change'])) {
    $form['select']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    $form['select']['#title'] = t('Changed');
  }

  $form['change'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Change!'),
    '#submit' => array('ajax_disable_test_change_submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_disable_test_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'select_box_wrapper',
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Submit handler to disable the select input, and then rebuild the form.
 * If the button was click with JS enabled, then ajax_form_callback() calls
 * ajax_disable_test_submit_ajax() to return just the changed part of the form.
 */
function ajax_disable_test_change_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['change']) {
    $form_state['select_is_disabled'] = true;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * Ajax callback
 *
 * @see ajax_disable_test_change_submit().
 */
function ajax_disable_test_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['select'];
}
```